# How do I change the data inside of a handle submit?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this code

```
   const [datadimentions, setdimentions] = useState("Hello")
    const [dataperiods, setdataperiods] = useState("World")

    const { handleSubmit } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            dimensions: datadimentions,
            periods: dataperiods
        }
    });
```

And I would like to change the data inside in a `useEffect`, for example:

```
useEffect(()=>{

     setdimentions("Good bye")
     setdataperiods("Cruel world")

 });
```

then I send the handle submit inside a return

```
  <anotherComponent handleSubmit={handleSubmit} >
```

yet when I use `console.log(this.props.handleSubmit)` inside this `antoherComponent` `dimensions` still has “hello” and `periods` still has “world”
¿Why is that happening?, and better yet, ¿is there a way to change the data inside `handleSubmit`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Other than missing `useEffect` dependency array which will cause render looping, how are you able to tell that state isn't updating? I doubt seriously that React is broken. Are you trying to console log state right after enqueueing a state update?

Comment: Can you share the whole component? This could help everyone to give you better answers.

Comment: i send handleSubmit={handleSubmit} to another component, and inside there it returns me(via console log)  that the data hasn't changed, the original code is 364 lines long, I made this code as an I guess easier to read question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are setting the default value of the form with the initial state of `datadimentions` and `dataperiods` but, from there, every changes made to one of them are not reflected on the form.

If you are using `react-hook-form` then you may set the default values with raw values or props and then change the form values with the `setValue` that `useForm` returns to you.

Something like the following:

```
const { handleSubmit, setValue } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
        dimensions: "Hello",
        periods: "World"
    }
});

// where you need to update one of the values
setValue('dimensions', 'New value')
```

Comment: You are a savior

Comment: Happy to have helped you.